# How can I perform a left join using mapstruct and jhipster?

Tags: jhipster, mapstruct

How can I perform a left join using the project structure that jhipster generated for me and mapstruct ? Im not sure how to merge the Disorder and Submission entities in the Mapper class below

```
@Repository
public interface DisorderRepository extends JpaRepository<Disorder, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT " +
          "new com.mohw.surveillance.app.service.dto.DisorderSubmissionDTO(d.id, d.name, SUM(s.amount)) " +
          "FROM Disorder d LEFT OUTER JOIN SubmissionCount s ON (d.id = s.disorder.id) " +
          "WHERE s.site.id = 11 AND s.createdDate BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date " +
          "GROUP BY s.disorder, d.name")
    Page<DisorderSubmissionDTO> getDisorderSubmissionasDTO(@Param("start_date") Date start_date, @Param("end_date") Date end_date);
}
```

I want to create a mapping for the left join above

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "submission_count")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class SubmissionCount implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Integer amount;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Date createdDate;

    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    private ZonedDateTime modifiedDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("submissioncounts")
    private Disorder disorder;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "disorder")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Disorder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "name", length = 200)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private ZonedDateTime createdDate;

    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    private ZonedDateTime modifiedDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "disorder")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<SubmissionCount> submissioncounts = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
public class DisorderSubmissionDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long disorder_id;
    private String disorder_name;
    private Long submissioncount_amount_sum;
}
```

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface DisorderSubmissionMapper extends EntityMapper<DisorderSubmissionDTO, Disorder> {

    @Mapping(source = "disorder.id", target = "disorder_id")
    @Mapping(source = "disorder.name", target = "disorder_name")
    DisorderSubmissionDTO toDto(Disorder disorder);

    Disorder toEntity(DisorderSubmissionDTO DisorderSubmissionDTO);

    default Disorder fromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Disorder disorder = new Disorder();
        disorder.setId(id);
        return disorder;
    }
}
```

Im not sure how to merge the Disorder and Submission entities in the Mapper class above

Comment: Do you absolutely want to use MapStruct? This would be trivial by writing manual code.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Could you point me in the direction of some documentation that can tell me how to do that?

Comment: Well JHipster uses MapStruct to build mappings between entities and DTOs. Here you are using a DTO projection in the repository, this is not exactly the same use case. I'm no longer sure now what is your question exactly, nor what your problem is. What have you tried?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Im trying to do a many to one mapping between disorder and submissioncount. can mapstruct handle a scenario like that? and you are right so I removed the DTO from the repository

Comment: Yes it can, check their doc. https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/ but ask yourself whether it's worth learning this lib versus writing simple mapping code manually.